# Intellitest code coverage

Tags: intellitest

I am using Intellitest 2015 to do data driven testing. My method is having two parameter 
MethodA(List class, string sourceType). When I am running the intellitest, the framework is passing arbitrary arguments such as control characters("\u0007","\u0008","\a" etc etc). I am preventing these strings by adding conditional statement at the top of my method. My Question is that when I am checking each special characters individually the number of block execution and run is more ie(39/87) but when I am adding these in a string[] array and checking all in one shot the number of blocks executing is gradually decreasing(18/87). How can i achieve maximum code block execution here. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is dynamic code coverage (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/test/developer-testing/intellitest-manual/input-generation#dynamic-code-coverage).

Please take a look at the following example of applying IntelliTest on a real world application to achieve full coverage: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/14/intellitest-hands-on/.